# Internet explorer displaying website problems

Tags: css, internet-explorer, opencart2.x

First I must say that this is a really great page, i found a lot of answers here already before. Also, excuse my english, there will probably be some mistakes :)

So, in order to speed up and make a good SEO on my website, I did a lot of things...The page runs on Opencart 2 system with theme Lamby and bunch of mods..
Probably one of them is now backfiring with problems which I'm getting when accessing [this page](https://www.misaron.si) in Internet explorer.

Funny part is that, I also made a page for my girl and on here page there are no problems with Internet explorer and I am using the same opencart theme.(her url: http://www.unikatnisvet.si/) 
So, the problem comes when accessing my main page on internet explorer on product page, some category pages...
I already found some guys on fiverr trying to fix this, but none of them successed or they were too expensive for my starting budget.
So now, I am asking you, good people of CSS and masters of internet, what is your idea, how to fix this...Problem seems to be on all version of IE.

It is realy disturbing because still a lot of my customers use IE....
Thank you, grazie, dankeschon, merci!

*(I looked and try to find an answer, but as newbie I am, i didn't understand them)*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem and post the code here? This will make it much easier for people to help with your problem.

Comment: Welcome to the world of web development. You will need to build a web site that works with the standards set out by the W3C and then another website to make it work with IE.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mike, but as newbie i have no idea what kind of a code should i post...I  read the linked article but i have no idea what to past, because with this my problem, i dont even know where to look... 
All i can do is to past image how website should look(google chrome: http://shrani.si/f/1M/t5/4ogvZvAD/product-page-google-chro.jpg) and how it looks with bugs(internet explorer: http://shrani.si/f/1n/As/3PNXariF/product-page-internet-ex.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand a thing + there are many details not relevant to your problem ==> rewrite your question please !

Comment: Question is: How to make my main website compatible with Internet explorer. Now its bugged on product page - see the image in my previous coment.
Also, i was explaing that i don't understand how can i have this problem, because i made a same page - opencart 2 system with same theme, for my girlfirend, and hers webiste- product page looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done much analysis on your problem, but IE is reporting a lot of the same error: `The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object`. This looks like a problem with jquery not loading properly or something like that

Can you try to put all your jquery code inside the `$(document).ready(function() {}` function?

Comment: Thank you for your help...
I don't understand corectly, you want me to past all linked jquery code as for an example: <script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
in header tpl?

Comment: No. Leave everything that's in the header where it is. But every code that's on the body and uses the `$` signal, put it inside the `$(document).ready`

Comment: I wish i would understand which file should i modify.... Not header.tpl? 
And in the body tag, where is $ i should insert $(document).ready ?
Thank you for you assistance....

Comment: Inside you body I find code like this: `if ( ($(window).height() + 100) < $(document).height() ) {`. This code should be inside the `$(document).ready(function() {` that I also see in your page code. This is one of many examples I can find

Comment: So, this is in footer.tpl, now i should put $(document).... before this if (  ($(window...)
Those are probably stupid questions for you, but i really don't know what am i supposed to search... So i am really glad for your assistance... :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with .tpl files or open cart but do the following. Find every block of code that has the `$(whatever)` code and make sure that that code is inside inside a `document.ready`. If you open developer tools in IE (press F12) you can find the errors (you need to refresh the page after pressing F12) http://postimg.org/image/4sjyholjp/

Comment: I tried, but then i made other mistakes...I should probably pay someone to do this for me...
Thank you for your help @JSantos

Comment: Good luck with that. Regards

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved my Internet explorer problem and i will tell you what it was, so maybe it can help someone else in the future.
The adresses of scripts and links in header should always start like this:
..//catalog/......
So, what is important is that before slashes, there should be double dots.
internet explorer reads this as root.

So if you have similar problem and it only happens in internet explorer, try adding two dots in the front of adress of scripts.

Page: https://www.misaron.si/
Regards,